# Information on eos block

Tags: nodeos

500ms generate 1 block.
May I ask you?

1. How many megabytes is the maximum in block?
2. When a block reaches Maximum block size, will it move to the next block?

Thank for view and reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1MB max block size on EOS mainnet. You can query with
`cleos get table eosio eosio global`

Transactions that don't make it into the current block will be queued for subsequent blocks.

Comment: thank you for reply.

Comment: Average 1 transaction is about 1kb? So in 500ms can only process 1000 transactions?
1. if 10 000 transactions in 500 ms, will have 9000 transactions waiting for next block?
2. Blockchain eos can't handle more?